# mount to the share file folders

Tags: 14.04, mount, samba

Here is one problem when I tried to mount the share folders for copying files

from ubuntu16.04 LTS to my windows 7 file systems

I used the following command to access the shared behaveiors:

```
paultsai@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount.cifs //192.168.43.180/share2 /mnt/SHARE --verbose -o rw,username=PaulTsai
[sudo] password for paultsai: 
Password for PaulTsai@//192.168.43.180/share2:  ************
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.43.180,unc=\\192.168.43.180\share2,user=PaulTsai,pass=********
paultsai@ubuntu:/mnt/SHARE$ cp ~/errors_http500 .
cp: cannot create regular file './errors_http500': Permission denied
```

I have tried to change the folders properties and used root to do the above
operations(by adding `sudo` commands before the `above commands`) . But it still failed, what should I do to make it executable ? I felt really strange about this !!

Answer (score 0):

CIFS security has been tightened in recent kernel releases. You might want to add *iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,noserverino* to your options, in other words:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.43.180/share2 /mnt/SHARE --verbose -o rw,username=PaulTsai,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,noserverino
```